# Trouble with returning user input with abstract class

Tags: java

I'm supposed to get the user input of the color of the triangle and the width and height of the triangle but, I can't even display the output. Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated since I am just learning about abstract classes in school now. thank you.

triangle class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
private double base;
private double height;
private int color;

public Triangle() {
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Enter a width for triangle:");
 double base = Integer.parseInt(input.nextInt());


 System.out.println("Enter height for triangle:");

 double height = Integer.parseInt(input.nextInt());
 }

 public Triangle(double base, double height) {
 this.base = base;
 this.height = height;
 this.color = color;
 }



public double getBase() {
return base;
}


public void setWidth(double width) {
 this.base = base;
 }


 public double getHeight() {
  return height;
}

 public int getColor(){
  return color;
 }

 public void setHeight(double height) {
 this.height = height;
}
public void setColor(int color){
this.color = color;
}
@Override 
 public double getArea() {
return 0.5* base * height;
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
return 2 * (base + height);
}
}
```

here is the GeometricClass:

```
 public abstract class GeometricObject {
 private String color = "white";
 private boolean filled;
 private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  /** Construct a default geometric object */
  protected GeometricObject() {
  dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

   /** Construct a geometric object with color and filled value */
   protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
   dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  this.color = color;
  this.filled = filled;
  }



  /** Set a new color */
  public void setColor(String color) {
  this.color = color;
  }


 public boolean isFilled() {
return filled;
}

 /** Set a new filled */
 public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
this.filled = filled;
}

  /** Get dateCreated */
 public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
  return dateCreated;
  }

   @Override
  public String toString() {
  return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color +
  " and filled: " + filled;
   }

   /** Abstract method getArea */
  public abstract double getArea();

  /** Abstract method getPerimeter */
 public abstract double getPerimeter();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of flaws on your code:

1) `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` is missing. You must be getting compilation error.

2) `Integer.parseInt` takes `String` parameter.

3) Why are you assigning `int` to `double`. Instead use `Double.parseDouble`.

4) Your constructor `Triangle(double base, double height)` has two parameters and still you are writing `this.color = color;`. Why?

5) `int color;` why color is `int`? Should be `String`.

6) `color` is present on parent class. Why are you adding another on child class then?

These points must be followed.

I made some basic changes Try the rest by yourself. Here's the modified code:

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    private double base;
    private double height;
    private int color;

    public Triangle() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a width for triangle:");
        double base = Double.parseDouble("" + input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Enter height for triangle:");

        double height = Double.parseDouble("" + input.nextInt());

        GeometricObject triangle = new Triangle(base, height);

        System.out.println("Area of triangle " + triangle.getArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter of triangle " + triangle.getPerimeter());
    }

    public Triangle(double base, double height) {
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return 0.5 * base * height;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (base + height);
    }
}
```

You have to explore yourself by reading the above code. Like why I've used below option:

```
GeometricObject triangle = new Triangle(base, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `input`? Where is it declared?

You should make a Scanner object pointing to System.in. In that way you can ask the user for input.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext() ) {
        System.out.println('Enter color');
        int color = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());


    }
```